# Whether to use a virtual actor or stateless service itself to do the database lookup?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-sql-database, actor, azure-service-fabric

I have the scenario of a user uploads an excel with a list of ids and get the associated data for the ids from SQL database. In Azure Service Fabric, i am using a Stateless Web API for the user to upload the excel file. What should be the best design approach for best performance and scalability (as large number of concurrent requests are expected).

1.
Excel File -> Stateless Web API -> Save the excel to Reliable Queue / Blob -> Extract ids from Excel -> Asynchronously Retrieve associated data for ids from Azure SQL as batch operation -> Return the formatted result

2.
Excel File -> Stateless Web API -> Save the excel to Reliable Queue / Blob -> Extract ids from Excel -> Spin up a stateless virtual actor to Asynchronously retrieve associated data for ids from Azure SQL as batch operation -> Return the formatted result

3.
Excel File -> Stateless Web API -> Spin up a Persistent Actor and pass Excel ->   Save the excel to Reliable Queue / Blob -> Extract ids from Excel -> Spin up a stateless virtual actor to Asynchronously retrieve associated data for ids from Azure SQL as batch operation -> Return the formatted result

or some other approach? Please advise me.

Comment: What do you mean by "virtual actor" and "persistent actor"?

Comment: Why do you think you need to save any blobs? You can process uploaded Excel files entirely in-memory without any disk IO or storage (blob or otherwise) needed.

Comment: virtual actor is one without any state and persistent actor has its state. If the excel is large should we save that to blob for asynchronous processing, as i remember earlier there was a timeout of 1 minute in azure for a request. So excel files used to be stored in BLOB and processed by a worker process. I am fine with in-memory processing, but my question is should i spin u an actor or not?

Comment: Actors are more useful when you have actual compute work to do. For I/O bound operations you can just stick to a stateless service. To further improve your model maybe you can store your data in a stateful service.

Comment: All actors in servicefabric are stateful and virtual. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-introduction): "Reliable Actors is a Service Fabric application framework based on the Virtual Actor pattern" and "An actor is an isolated, independent unit of compute and state ". See the "when to use " section in the provided link to determine they are a fit for your use-case.

Comment: My question is if i use an actor to process my i/o bound operation (excel processing, data retrieval from Azure SQL and packaging the return data) asynchronously would it free up the stateless service to cater more requests from other users ? Also if resources are limited in the node in which the stateless service picked the request, service fabric can instantiate actor in another node. Does these assumptions are true?

Comment: A stateless service by default runs on all nodes and requests will be spread amongst them so there already is loadbalancing in place for services as well. A stateless service instance can handle multiple concurrent requests. So for those reasons an Actor is not necessary in your case.